# conflict between hidden div and displayed div

Tags: css

I have a clickable div :

```
#next {
    cursor:cell;
    z-index:100;
}
```

That is activated by this JavaScript :

```
 $('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
 }
```

And the divs:

```
#zob {
    width: 100% ; height: 20px;
}

#zobbig {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100% ; 
    height: 250px; 
}
```

and when i hover on `#zob` then `#zobbig` appears.

```
#zob:hover ~#zobbig {
    cursor:alias;
    opacity:0.8; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
```

My problem is that when it appears it make my `#next` div unlickable even when i'm not hovering on `#zob`. A zone of `250px` (height of `#zobbig`) is disabling the click function of the `#next` div. 
I just want my `#next` div to be clickable as it is supposed to be.

Thanks for your help

Dan

(you can see it directly on http://blog.dansayag.com)

or on http://jsfiddle.net/CEtfh/108/

---

to make it easier: if you go on the fiddle there is a picture of bob dylan.
If you point with the cursor on the eye, the cursor becomes a cross. If you point on the hat, the cursor is normal.
I just want the cursor to be a cross on the entire bob dylan image...

IF you go on fiddle you will also understand what is ZOB and what is ZOBBIG

Comment: Please put this in a jsFiddle.net and simplify it for everyone to understand a little better

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/CEtfh/108/

Comment: The problem here is that your question is badly written, it's not entirely obvious what your problem is. What is zob and zobbig? neither of these elements are obvious when looking at either the fiddle or the website. I would suggest you reword your question so it's a little easier to understand :)

Comment: i'm sorry... when you just hover on #zob (which is the top bar) -> the result is to make #zobbig appear. But if you see, the #next div (containing the image is clickable area. When you hover on #next, the cursor changes). The problem is that the area where the cursor changes is not the entire #next div but only a portion of it. why ? because the #zobbig div which is hidden goes below it and there is a conflit between the two div. I only want the #next div to be entirely clickable..

Comment: do you understand my problem?

Comment: that is actually what is done. the div containing the image is clickable but not on the zone that is taken by ZOBBIG...

Comment: I realised after haha sorry bit tired. Give the answer below a go and comment on that if you have no luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CEtfh/125/) is a link to fiddle, where I made it a little bit clearer for everyone to see.

Your problem comes from the fact that you don't set display: none; to your elements, but you simply make them invisible. Therefore they still exist on the HTML page and must align according to each other and the clickable div with the image inside gets pushed down from the #zob div. I suggest you change your way of hiding elements in the biginning with

```
disply: none;
```

and later display them again with

```
display: block;
```

EDIT: Resize the window in fiddle so the picture is a little bit larger, otherwise there will be no clickable div at all

Comment: i'm sorry but on your example the cursor is still not active on the #zobbig div..

Comment: and i use opacity because otherwise i cannot use the transition effects so i cannot use display none

Comment: Another problem is the z-index of the div with the img. Maybe you can keep your logic, but set the z-index of the picture to be negative, when the zob is hidden. (With js, of course)

Comment: To see the coursor and clickable div, simply drag the output window to the left so the image is bigger. Or set its width to about 70%, then it should be fine ;)

Comment: but if z-index on zobbig is negative then it will be behing the img.. and we wont see it.....

Comment: That's our point. When its opacity is low (invisible) we put it behind the image so we can click on the image. After the image is clicked, we start our function, where you simply change the z-index back to normal, and the zob goes in front ;)